# Setting default value in html form date input

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

In a [[image]google-apps-script](/questions/tagged/google-apps-script), I have an html form with two date inputs. I want to set the default values to be the prior week of the current day.

I cannot get the following scripts to work. Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong?

I am getting a `"Object does not allow properties to be added or changed"` error.

Code.gs:

```
function pickDates() {
  var d = new Date();
  var e = new Date();
  d.setDate((d.getDate() - d.getDay() % 7) - 7);
  e.setDate(e.getDate() - (e.getDay() + 1) % 7);
  d = d.getFullYear() + '-' + (d.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + d.getDate();
  e = e.getFullYear() + '-' + (e.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + e.getDate();
  var htmlB = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Pick Dates').setWidth(200).setHeight(200);
  htmlB.d = d;
  htmlB.e = e;
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlB, 'Select Dates');
}
```

Pick Dates.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base target="_top">
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    Start Date<br>
    <input id="start" type="date" name="startDay">
    <br><br> End Date<br>
    <input id="end" type="date" name="endDay">
    <br><br>
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="google.script.run
            .withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close)
            .sendEmails(this.parentNode)" />
  </form>
  <script>
    document.getElementById('start').value = d;
    document.getElementById('end').value = e;
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I cannot get them to work"? Are they producing an error? This is confusing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To [evaluate()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-template#evaluate()) the dates in the template, you will need to use [createTemplateFromFile()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-service#createTemplateFromFile(String)). The error is because the [HtmlOutput](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output#) object returned from `createHtmlOutputFromFile()` can not have properties added like `htmlB.d = d;`. You can use a html template with [scriptlets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#scriptlets) instead

```
function pickDates() {
  var d = new Date();
  var e = new Date();
  d.setDate((d.getDate() - d.getDay() % 7) - 7);
  e.setDate(e.getDate() - (e.getDay() + 1) % 7);
  d = d.getFullYear() + '-' + (d.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + d.getDate();
  e = e.getFullYear() + '-' + (e.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + e.getDate();

  // create a template
  var htmlB = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Pick Dates');
  htmlB.d = d;
  htmlB.e = e;

  // evaluate() returns HtmlOuput object
  var modal_html = htmlB.evaluate().setWidth(200).setHeight(200);

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(modal_html, 'Select Dates');
}
```

Pick Dates.html - add the printing scriptlets

```
...

  <script>
    document.getElementById('start').value = <?= d ?>;
    document.getElementById('end').value = <?= e ?>;
  </script>
</body>
```